# Problem clicking an href=javascript using selenium web drive python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am having an problem with clicking an menu item that has an link with an href with selenium web drive.

```
<a class="a-link-normal" href="javascript:;">Fiction</a>
```

Here is my code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="div-fiction"]/span/a').click()
```

This only seem to hover over the linked name and highlight it but does not trigger the javascript. I tried reading all the other solutions but it all lead to just using the click() method. Does anyone know what is wrong or a different approach to this.

Comment: did you try with js click ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element seems to be a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Fiction"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='a-link-normal' and contains(.,'Fiction')]"))).click()
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", webelement to click)
```